# How to downgrade Nautilus 3 to Nautilus 2.xx?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus

I want to use Nautilus Elementary with Ubuntu 11.10, mainly because of the integrated Coverflow effect and Gloobus preview. But I have one problem. Nautilus Elementary is a patch-up for Nautilus 2.xx (whichever version is used in Ubuntu 11.04).

This is the link to the tutorial on how to install Nautilus Elementary 2.32 on Ubuntu 11.04.

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/install-nautilus-elementary-2322-in.html

The problem is, I need to use Ubuntu 11.10. So, how do I downgrade my Nautilus 3 (which is the default version in Ubuntu 11.10) to Nautilus 2.xx which is used in Ubuntu 11.04?

I am also aware of my other options (I have done a lot of research on this)

1. Download Gloobus Sushi - The Cover Flow effect is not available to the public yet - as shown on the Gloobus website http://gloobus.net. (I still like the previewing function)
2. Download  Marlin  - Still no CoverFlow (although I like the concept).

Can someone please show me how to do this? I can't seem to find any solution to this problem, even on AskUbuntu (I guess I'm the only one who is aking about this).

Answer (score 1):

You can't, 11.10 uses GTK+3 instead of the GTK+2 libraries and so, thus, does Nautilus 2.

There is no easy way you can install Nautilus 2 in your 11.10 system and Nautilus Elementary is not available for 11.10.

If you are that desperate to use those features you can stick with 10.04, supported until April 2013, or 11.04, supported until October this year.